# libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector zsh: abort

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a code mainly for a function 'getCasesOverTime' in the CovidCaseMap class that returns a vector of these TimeAndCaseData objects. TimeAndCaseData class is for recording the number of active cases from some point in time. getCasesOverTime function tales an int parameter of how many hours we are assuming a case is active for.

Here is the code

`

```
#ifndef COVIDCASEMAP_H
#define COVIDCASEMAP_H

#include "CovidCase.h"

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <string>
using std::string;


//Record the number of active cases from some point in time
class TimeAndCaseData
{
    private:
        int time;
        int currentCases;
        
    public:
        //constructor
        TimeAndCaseData(const int timeIn, const int currentCasesIn)
        {
            time = timeIn;
            currentCases = currentCasesIn;
        }
        
        int & getTime()
        {
            return time;
        }

        int & getNumberOfCases()
        {
            return currentCases;
        }
};

class CovidCaseMap
{
    private:
        vector<CovidCase> covidCases;
    public:
        void addCase(const CovidCase & c)
        {
            covidCases.push_back(c);
        }

        vector<TimeAndCaseData> & getCasesOverTime(int activeHours)
        {
            vector<TimeAndCaseData> data;
            vector<int> caseTime;

            for(int i = 0; i < covidCases.size(); i++)
            {
                caseTime.push_back(covidCases[i].getTime());
            }

            sort(caseTime.begin(), caseTime.end());

            data.push_back(TimeAndCaseData(0,0));
            
            for(int j = 1; j < caseTime.size()*2+1; j++)
            {
                if(j==1) data.push_back(TimeAndCaseData(caseTime[0], 1));
                if(caseTime[j-1]+activeHours < caseTime[j])
                {
                    data.push_back(TimeAndCaseData(caseTime[j-1]+activeHours, data[j-  1].getNumberOfCases()-1));
                }
                
                else if (caseTime[j] < caseTime[j-1]+activeHours)
                {
                    data.push_back(TimeAndCaseData(caseTime[j], data[j-1].getNumberOfCases()+1));
                }

                //when they are the same
                else
                {
                    data.push_back(TimeAndCaseData(caseTime[j], data[j-1].getNumberOfCases()));
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
};
```

`

And this is the test code

`

```
#include "CovidCaseMap.h"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::pair;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    
    int retval = 0;
    
    
    CovidCaseMap m;
    m.addCase(CovidCase(51.75186263338416,-0.3356807902,"48763f26d6b",21,5));
    m.addCase(CovidCase(51.75166927531987,-0.3455440017,"48763f3b5ef",24,8));
    m.addCase(CovidCase(51.75293227875113,-0.3363451467,"48763f26e9b",19,73));
    m.addCase(CovidCase(51.751442536246415,-0.3384676374,"48763f23ff9",35,117));
    m.addCase(CovidCase(51.750621522352574,-0.3373409116,"48763f21445",42,142));
    
    vector<pair<int,int> > rightAnswer;
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(0,0);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(5,1);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(8,2);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(73,3);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(117,4);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(125,3);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(128,2);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(142,3);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(193,2);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(237,1);
    rightAnswer.emplace_back(262,0);
    
    
    vector<TimeAndCaseData> active = m.getCasesOverTime(120);
    
    if (active.size() == 0) {
        cout << "An empty vector was returned, the test cannot pass\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rightAnswer.size(); ++i) {        
        
        cout << "Entry " << i << ": expecting time = " << rightAnswer[i].first << ", cases = " << rightAnswer[i].second; 
        
        if (i >= active.size()) {
            cout << " -- not enough entries in the answer from the getCasesOverTime function\n";
            ++retval;
            continue;            
        }
        if (rightAnswer[i].first == active[i].getTime() && rightAnswer[i].second == active[i].getNumberOfCases()) {
            cout << " -- got it\n";
        } else {
            cout << " -- instead got time = " << active[i].getTime() << ", cases = " << active[i].getNumberOfCases() << "\n";
            ++retval;
        }
    }
    
    return retval;
}
```

`

When I tried to compile, there was no issue but when I tried to run it, I've got an error message as title. How can I fix this? Thank you

I very new to C++ and couldn't find a way yet.

Comment: It's good time to learn a debugger and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<TimeAndCaseData> & getCasesOverTime(int activeHours)` returns a reference to a `vector`, but the `vector` is local in your function, it gets destroyed when the function ends, you have a dangling reference. The fix is to remove the `&`, then you will return a copy of the `vector`.

Another problem is with `for(int j = 1; j < caseTime.size()*2+1; j++)` and all the `caseTime[j]` accesses, they are way out of bounds. The crash goes away when removing `*2+1`.

https://godbolt.org/z/nT8MKzfao

Several compiler warnings, you should fix them.